# Why am I not getting the changed payload after consuming JMS queue in Mule?

Tags: java, queue, jms, mule

i've made a flow with JMS using ActiveMQ, i send a message to the queue, but for any reason when im trying to consume from the queue, get the message and change it by setting the new payload, it doesn't change. What am i doing wrong?

Basically i want to send back the changed payload through HTTP response

Here's my code:

```
 <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" 
            specification="1.1" 
            brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" 
            validateConnections="true" 
            doc:name="Active MQ"                                
            persistentDelivery="true"               
            />      

<flow name="jmsFlow1" doc:name="jmsFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="jms" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#['This is a message test']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[true]">
            <processor-chain>
                <logger message="Im here!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="StudioIN" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS Queue Studio IN" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
    </choice>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" category="//// RETURNED FROM QUEUE PAYLOAD" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>

<flow name="fmsAdapterConsumerFlow1" doc:name="fmsAdapterConsumerFlow1">
    <jms:outbound-endpoint  queue="StudioIN" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS StudioIN Consumer" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    <set-payload value="#[payload + ' returned from queue']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Note: though it works with a string, better use a boolean: `<when expression="#[true]">`

Comment: @DavidDossot thanks for that David. Updated the mule xml so you can see that ive applied your changes :( but doesnt work here. Dont know why

Comment: You have a copy/paste issue: "fmsAdapterConsumerFlow1" should start with in inbound endpoint not an outbound endpoint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify the `exchange-pattern` on the `jms:outbound-endpoint` and `jms:inbound-endpoint`. Therefore Mule uses the default, which is `one-way`. So it's impossible that the payload change made in `fmsAdapterConsumerFlow1` get replied to `jmsFlow1`.

Set `exchange-pattern="request-response"` on both JMS endpoints and also set `disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="false"` on the connector otherwise you'll never receive any response.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm having a {NullPayload}, weird :O
INFO  2013-07-30 17:03:50,770 [[jmsptpexample].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] //// RETURNED FROM QUEUE PAYLOAD: {NullPayload}

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me on 3.3.0. Note that I had to remove the trailing space in `"#[payload + ' returned from queue']"` otherwise I receive "#[payload + ' returned from queue'] " instead of "This is a message test returned from queue" as the HTTP response.

Comment: yeah still getting nullpayload :(

Comment: You have a copy/paste issue: "fmsAdapterConsumerFlow1" should start with in inbound endpoint not an outbound endpoint :)

Comment: omg it worked, Thanks!!!! :) so basically inbound is to read and modify and outbound would be only for reading?

Comment: Inbound is for receiving and outbound for sending.

Answer (score 1):

The second flow mentioned above is to be changed. 
This flow starts with a inbound-endpoint if it has to read a message and process it.

```
<flow name="fmsAdapterConsumerFlow1" doc:name="fmsAdapterConsumerFlow1">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint  queue="StudioIN" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS StudioIN Consumer" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    <set-payload value="#[payload + ' returned from queue']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

Hope this helps.